# Returning a list of filenames with keywords associated with it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why I get an empty list I test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def find_images_with_keyword(key_dict, keywords_list):
'''(dict of {str: list of str}, list of str) -> list
Given a keyword_dictionary and a list of keywords,
return the list of filenames associated with the given keywords.
The list of filenames should include all filenames having one or more
of the specified keywords(ie, a filename may be associated with only one,
not all of the keywords in the list).
>>> find_images_with_keyword({'dog': ['1.png', '2.png'], 'animal': ['1.png',  '3.png']}, ['dog', 'animal'])
  ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
'''
new_list = []
for keyword in key_dict.items():
    for filename in keywords_list:
        if keyword == filename:
            new_list.append(filename)
return new_list
```

Comment: you have two `for` loops that use `keyword` as the name for the current item - I'm assuming one of those is supposed to be `filename`? Otherwise it's unclear what that variable is supposed to be

Comment: can you tidy up your question? What's the input, what's the expected output?

Comment: `filename` is not defined.

Comment: the output is given in the docstring. I know filename is not defined, but I'm not sure where to define it.

Comment: Read about [how to iterate over a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops). `for keyword in key_dict:`

Comment: But the filename is in a sublist of a dictionary

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but I still get an empty list when I try to test it.

Comment: new_list = []
    for keyword, filename in key_dict.items():
        if filename in range(len(keywords_list)):
            new_list.append(filename)
    return new_list

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def find_images_with_keyword(key_dict, keywords_list):
    '''(dict of {str: list of str}, list of str) -> list
    Given a keyword_dictionary and a list of keywords,
    return the list of filenames associated with the given keywords.
    The list of filenames should include all filenames having one or more
    of the specified keywords(ie, a filename may be associated with only one,
    not all of the keywords in the list).
    >>> find_images_with_keyword({'dog': ['1.png', '2.png'], 'animal': ['1.png',  '3.png']}, ['dog', 'animal'])
      ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
    '''

    found_imgs = set()
    for keyword, value in key_dict.items():
        if keyword in keywords_list:
            found_imgs = found_imgs.union(set(value))
    return found_imgs

print find_images_with_keyword({'dog': ['1.png', '2.png'], 'animal': ['1.png', '3.png']}, ['dog', 'animal'])
```

---

EDIT: add `list` version based on yours.

```
def find_images_with_keyword(key_dict, keywords_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in key_dict.items():
        key, filenames = item
        if key in keywords_list:
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename not in new_list:  # add this
                    new_list.append(filename)
    return new_list
```

Comment: Look at my new post, may help a lot.

Comment: It's much clearer now, but why does the if statement come before the second for loop?

Comment: And how can I get '1.png' just to return once? It returns twice when I test it.

Comment: So I used set. I edit the `list` version, have a look and do more practice :)